# How to run a script in a screen on reboot

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

I want to start a blocking server in a screen on reboot, so that I may access it later.

The command `screen -d -m /home/dataserv/www/start_production_server.sh` works on its own just fine regardless from where its called, but does not if used as a crontab entry.

```
dataserv@dataserv-dev:~$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot echo "test" > /home/dataserv/reboot.txt 2>&1
@reboot screen -d -m /home/dataserv/www/start_production_server.sh
```

The test entry works fine so I'm quite puzzled as to why its failing.

Comment: Did you try to type the absolute path of screen (I guess `/usr/bin/screen` instead of just `screen`)?

Comment: Have you checked permissions?

Comment: I also tried with the absolute path, which did not help. The permissions are right as the reboot.txt file was created by the dataserv user.

Comment: Have you checked any logs to give some indication as to why it's failing? I'm not sure if screen has a -v option or a log.

Comment: If you add the `-L` option (before -`d`, for instance), screen will log output into the cron user's home directory (perhaps yours), naming the file `screenlog.0`.  If you need more debugging help, turning on the script trace (e.g., `#!/bin/sh -x` at the top) might help.  Since you haven't posted the server script, there's really not enough information to do more than suggest ways for you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Running the `screen` command from `cron` and capturing its *stderr* reports this message:

```
Must run suid root for multiuser support.
```

A quick search around results in the discovery that this message is printed when `screen` has no `tty` device from which it can build its session name. (Normally the session name is something like `11597.pts-0.myhostname`.) Further reading of the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) shows that the `-S` flag can be used to specify a session name:

```
screen -md -S "atboot.$(hostname)" ...
```

There's nothing special about the "atboot" label; I used it to remind me that the process was started at boot time and didn't have a tty.

Combining this with your `crontab` specification leads to this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot echo "test" > /home/dataserv/reboot.txt 2>&1
@reboot screen -d -m -S "atboot.$(hostname)" /home/dataserv/www/start_production_server.sh
```

Running `screen -ls` will give an output similar to this:

```
11732.atboot.myhostname      (03/01/16 00:25:01)     (Detached)
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @fabe it worked for me. Can you please try replacing `"atboot.$(hostname)"` with just `"atboot"` in case it's a shell or `$PATH` issue